# How do I detect a user entering emojis, special/foreign characters and other input in Javascript - there is no keyup event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari

On a Mac it is possible to enter emojis (via the emoji keyboard that comes up when you press control-cmd-space) or to enter accented versions of characters by holding a key down until options appear.  Using these methods does not trigger a keyup or keydown event, so javascript that is intended to update things on user input is not being fired.  How do I detect this kind of input?  The change event doesn't fire until a user moves out a text input field, and I'm looking for things to happen as-you-type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out can detect these by looking for an 'input' event.

Comment: They input event is the correct way to handle this indeed. Not only for emojis put also for copy paste commands, scripted input, etc. Please accept your own answer so we know you don't need further assistance.